# Does KAPT(Kotlin Annotation Processing) support Kotlin-JS?

Tags: annotations, kotlin, annotation-processing, kapt

I see an [example](https://github.com/JetBrains/kotlin-examples/tree/master/gradle/kotlin-code-generation) explains KATP for Kotlin JVM, which is working.

I wonder if it supports Kotlin JS? Is there any example?

Answer (score 2):

No, kapt does not support Kotlin/JS. kapt integrates into the Java compiler and uses its annotation processing API, and none of this exists in the Kotlin/JS compilation pipeline.

Comment: Thanks! Is there any plan?

Comment: kapt is inherently tied to javac, so any annotation processing tool for Kotlin/JS or Native would be a completely separate design. At this time we're not working on any such tool.

Answer (score 0):

I found a library that does it https://github.com/Foso/MpApt

From README:

> I wrote an annotation processing libary that can detect annotations in Kotlin Native/JS and Jvm projects, because Kapt is only working with KotlinJvm. The library can be used in Kotlin Compiler plugins. Tested with Kotlin 1.3.41, 1.3.50, 1.3.71